# Display image using Blazor

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am new to Blazor and I have googled for two days now to try and find a solution to my problem... Is it possible to upload an image from a file directory to a specific location on a website using Blazor? I managed to place the image in the top left corner using

```
<img src="/Images/image.jpg" asp-append-version="true" width="300px"/>
```

in the html, body{...}.

Is there a way to place it in the bottom left corner in the navigation bar instead? Or anywhere else besides the top left corner? If so, where and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blazor is basically a tool for interacting with HTML.  It has very little to do with positioning.

In order to position elements on a page, you'll need to learn about HTML and CSS.  I also recommend studying Bootstrap, since the default Blazor app comes with Bootstrap already built-in.

In order to get an answer to your question, you should search google (or watch YouTube videos): "CSS How to place ____ at bottom of screen."  The only thing Blazor will do is allow you to CHANGE styles or css classes at will-- but you still have to know what styles and classes to use.